# How to get position with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
Name         Total
Foo          7
FoBarr       2
Fobarr2      2
Foobar       5
FBar         8
FBar2        8
FBar3        8
FbarL        9
```

What I actually want is not a way to get the position like this:

```
Name    Total    Position
FoBarr     2        1st
FoBarr2    2        1st
Foobar     5        3rd     // notice that there is no 2nd position
Foo        7        4th
FBar       8        5th
FBar2      8        5th
FBar3      8        5th
FbarL      9        8th    // notice that there is no 6th and 7th...
```

I would appreciate an SQL query solution for this, though I'm working on a php application too.

I have searched, and I believe this problem does not exactly fall under the rank function as such, because the position does not just go on sequentially like that if there are ties.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you skipping 2nd, 6th and 7th? There is probably a way to grab relative position - but not if you're skipping rows, it might have to be done in code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Comment: @A.Chiesa, this is not a duplicate of that particular problem. See here that when for instance, there is a tie in two totals, the position skips the position after the second and goes to the next

Comment: Read the second answer, please... It IS a duplicate. What you serch is the RANK function, which MySQL does not support directly, but can be emulated. You're better off searching for that.

Comment: @ahoffner I am skipping 2nd because FoBarr2 which is the 2nd item is now in 1st position, so the next will be 3rd (this was a requirement) - This also makes it possible for the last position to tally with the total number of items.   Here, I have 8 items, and the last position is 8th...

Comment: @A.Chiesa,It is NOT a dupliate. Yes, in the 2nd answer there is a duplicate, but the positions are in sequential order( this is where I actually have an issue). Mine, the positions do not follow this order if there are duplicates (this is a requirement).

Comment: Your rank_column is the total column. What is different from the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooook, so, if this is not an actual duplicate, let me just elaborate on the answer I linked before:

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @count = 0;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT Name, total,
@count := @count + 1 as RowNumber,
CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = total THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := total THEN @rank_count := @count
END AS Position
FROM rank_table
ORDER BY total
```

What you want to do is take 2 counters, 1 is going to be incremented by one for every row, the other is going to keep the ranking value, to be reset to the first counter when the value changes.

See [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62db0/5) for a SQL Fiddle.